# FileProvider.getUriForFile is throwing StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fileprovider

First thing to mention, answers to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47931146/fileprovider-geturiforfile-is-causing-stringindexoutofboundsexception) do not help.

The source code looks like the following:

```
Intent intent    = new Intent("com.mycompany.action.PICK_FILE");
String authority = "com.mycompany.fileprovider";
File   file      = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

intent.setData(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, authority, file));
```

`FileProvider.getUriForFile` is throwing the exception and here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=16
at java.lang.String.indexAndLength(String.java:500)
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1313)
at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:687)
at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:377)
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml` inside of `application` tag I have added the following:

```
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.mycompany.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" 
            />
        </provider>
```

Content of `file_paths.xml` is the following:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="input_files"  path="." />
    <external-path name="output_files" path="MyAppName/" />
</paths>
```

`output_files` path is not used in this context.

I have run debugger through `FileProvider.SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile()`. Relevant code snippet is the following (lines 683-688):

```
            final String rootPath = mostSpecific.getValue().getPath();
            if (rootPath.endsWith("/")) {
                path = path.substring(rootPath.length());
            } else {
                path = path.substring(rootPath.length() + 1);
            }
```

`rootPath` is evaluated as `/storage/sdcard` which is also the exact value of `path`, so it's not wonder that the exception is thrown.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

As suggested bellow, passed `java.io.File` should not be a directory. [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider#geturiforfile) are ambiguous and never say that explicitly. The workaround would be to create uri 'manually'. Thus

```
intent.setData(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, authority, file));
```

should be replaced with:

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://" + file.getAbsolutePath()));
```

Comment: Your `file` isn't a file. It's a directory. You need to pass a `File` object that points to a specific file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Third params to getUriForFile, should be your path to your file with file name. [Here is an docs, read it](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider#geturiforfile).

Comment: I have read the docs and it clearly states: "`file` - `File`: A `File` pointing to the filename for which you want a content `Uri`." `java.io.File` can be either directory or file. Docs never say that it shouldn't be a directory. However, that indeed is a problem and I will accept your answer.